# Returning data/body along with an HttpReponseCode?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I'm looking at creating a REST WebAPI and want to return "error" messages along with my status codes - as desciption to the end client as to what went wrong.

One of the responses will be a 422 status code - but I can't see how to get the data element into my reponse?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetValidate(string number)
{
   var response = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422);
   response.Content new { error = "something wrong here", item = "number" }; // This is wrong!

   return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definition in the `HttpStatusCode` for `422` code. Take a look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You could use the 500 http status code which is `Interval Error`:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new {error = "something wrong here", item = "number"});
```

or 400 `Bad Request`:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new { error = "something wrong here", item = "number" });
```

Comment: You are correct, there is no 422 in the ENUM, but it IS a perfectly valid and widely used code.

Comment: return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)422, new { error = "something wrong here", item = "number" });

Answer (score 0):

`return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "message");` or other overloads.

Answer (score 0):

There is a draft proposal to the IETF for a standard way of returning error information from an API.  The details are here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-04

I have a library that supports creating this format on [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Tavis.Problem/0.8.0-beta) and a [GitHub project](https://github.com/tavis-software/Tavis.Problem).

It works like this..

```
 var problem = new ProblemDocument
        {
            ProblemType = new Uri("http://example.org"),
            Title = "Houston we have a problem",
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
            ProblemInstance = new Uri("http://foo")
        };

        problem.Extensions.Add("bar", new JValue("100"));

 var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)
        {
            Content = new ProblemContent(problem)
        };
```